# aggregate framework, group and average

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a dataset like below:

```
Student,Test1,Test2,Test3
Saeed,59,94,81
Sam,60,77,81
Sammy,77,77,77
Saman,76,76,34
Shah,19,61,72
```

I want to get the student name with the highest overall average.

First, I tried to get the average for each student but my query has errors. I don't understand why.

```
db.students.aggregate({$group : {_id:"$Student", Average: {$avg:["$Test1", "$Test2", "$Test3"]}}})
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `$group` stage.

Use `$project` to calculate the `$avg` followed by `$sort` desc and `$limit` to 1.

```
db.students.aggregate({
    $project: {
        Student: 1,
        avg: {
            $avg: ["$Test1", "$Test2", "$Test3"]
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        avg: -1
    }
}, {
    $limit: 1
})
```

For reference `$avg`
 https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/

Comment: what if there are two students with the same highest average?

Comment: You can add `$group` stage `{
    $group: {_id:"$avg", students:{$push:"$Student"}}
}` before `$sort` and `$limit`, which will push the students with same average.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!! I tried to use a different logic but don't know how to write the codes: first use $project to get $avg, then $group get $max. db.students.aggregate(
{$project: {_id: "$Student", Avg: {$avg: ["$Test1","$Test2","$Test3"] }}},
{$group: {_id:"$Student", Max : {$max: "$Avg"}}}) But the result is like this{ "_id" : null, "Max" : 94.66666666666667 }. I want to also display student name and each test score.

Comment: Try `db.students.aggregate( {$project: {_id: "$Student", Avg: {$avg: ["$Test1","$Test2","$Test3"] }}}, {$group: {_id:"$_id", Max : {$max: "$Avg"}}})`. The `$project` stage only keeps fields that you list in the stage.

Comment: Thank you! This query gave me _id:null, max. How do I also display that student name and his each test scores?

Comment: Np. Have you used my query ? Specifically this part `{$group: {_id:"$_id",`. It should't be null. This is complete query to include test scores.`db.students.aggregate( {$project: {_id: "$Student", Test1:1, Test2:1, Test3:1, Avg: {$avg: ["$Test1","$Test2","$Test3"] }}}, {$group: {_id:"$_id", Max : {$max: "$Avg"}, Test1:{$push:"$Test1}, Test2:{$push:"$Test2}, Test3:{$push:"$Test3}}})`